# Remove the last empty line in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

```
nf=open(Output_File,'w+')
with open(Input_File,'read') as f:
    for row in f:
        Current_line = str(row)
        Reformated_line=str(','.join(Current_line.split('|')[1:-1]))
        nf.write(Reformated_line+ "\n")
```

I'm trying to read `Input file` which is in Table Format and write it in a CSV file, but my Output contains one last empty line also. How can I remove the last empty line in CSV?

Comment: Asides: Is there a reason you open one file with `with`, but not the other? Also, why do you call `str(row)`? Since `row` is already a `str`, this doesn't seem to accomplish anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an empty line in your input file. From your comments, you actually have a non-empty line that has no `|` characters in it. In either case, it is easy enough to check for an empty result line.

Try this:

```
#UNTESTED
nf=open(Output_File,'w+')
with open(Input_File,'read') as f:
    for row in f:
        Current_line = str(row)
        Reformated_line=str(','.join(Current_line.split('|')[1:-1]))
        if Reformatted_line:
            nf.write(Reformated_line+ "\n")
```

Other notes:

- You should use `with` consistently. Open both files the same way.
- `str(row)` is a no-op. `row` is already a str.
- `str(','.join(...))` is similarly redundant.
- `open(..., 'read')` is not a valid use of the mode parameter to `open()`. You should use `r` or even omit the parameter altogether.
- I prefer not to introduce new names when changing the format of existing data. That is, I prefer `row = row.split()` over `Reformatted_line = row.split()`.

Here is a version that incorporates these and other suggestions:

```
with open(Input_File) as inf, open(Output_File, 'w+') as outf:
    for row in inf:
        row = ','.join(row.split('|')[1:-1])
        if row:
            outf.write(row + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks Rob . Am new to Python . I changed the Script as per your suggestion . But I am still getting the empty line in the Output . There is no  empty line in my Input . But below is how my last line in Input looks like :                    ---------------------------

Comment: My 2nd example above should work correctly on your input. If it does not, please edit your question to include a short, **complete** sample program that demonstrates the problem. Include sample input, if required. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @Prashanth_Ramanathan - I have updated my first example to deal with the input you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Just a question of reordering things a little:

```
first = True
with open(Input_File,'read') as f, open(Output_File,'w+') as nf:
    for row in f:
        Current_line = str(row)
        Reformated_line=str(','.join(Current_line.split('|')[1:-1]))
        if not first:
            nf.write('\n')
        else:
            first = False
        nf.write(Reformated_line)
```

Comment: You can `open` multiple files in a single `with` statement. Otherwise, don't forget to close `nf`